# Efficient database query - avoiding reevaluation on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, activerecord

I was wondering if someone could provide some guidance in terms of the best approach to take in addressing a problem I am facing with a rails application.

**Background**
I have a large database called `Product` which contains around 500,000 lines.  I would like to create a page (this could be called "Details") which enables users to view information for a subsection of the items in `Product`.

Initially i want to run an active record query on `Product`, yielding `@matchingproducts` - e.g. `@matchingproducts = Product.where(...)`.

There are 2 slight complications:

1. `@matchingproducts` typically contains around 200 records, I am using paginate to show these results 50 at a time
2. I would like to be able to apply further filters to `@matchingproducts` to enable users to fine tune the results (e.g. `@matchingproducts_filtered = @matchingproducts.where(...)`)

**Problem**
How should I define my variable `@matchingproducts` in such a way that the query of the entire database (`Product`) is only performed once (i.e. on the initial load of the "Details" page?

Currently my time consuming query of `Product` is rerun each time I view the next x records using `paginate` as well as when `@matchingproducts_filtered` is specified by the user

Any guidance you can provide on this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe some indexes can help. Otherwise, cache all the things.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev for the response - I'll give it a go thanks.  So its ok to cache the result of a large active record query, it's not just limited to storing individual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio Tulentsev mentioned, you should ensure you have the correct indexes setup. 500,000 records is not a tremendous amount for a modern, production-quality DB on recent hardware, so with slowness in querying that might be one of the first things to look at.

If it is loading a lot of related associations/sub-associations, etc., it could be an n+1 query problem that an [includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) on the query may help with. If you look at the log and are debugging ActiveRecord queries, you might see a ton of queries for a single request and what you thought was a single query from looking at the code. That would be a sign of an n+1 query.

If you don't need to display some association/subassociation/etc. data, maybe you could do without it.

If you are doing heavy searching/filtering, you might look at [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)/SOLR. But exploring that will burn up more initial and recurring time than you need to be spending on this problem, so I wouldn't suggest it at this point. Just keep that in mind for later with complex and varying queries with a much larger dataset.

Unfortunately, these types of questions relating to increasing performance are really open-ended, as many factors can be involved, but hopefully this will help as a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I will have a go at applying some indexes and see what the effect it - it sounds hopeful though...  My setup is very simple with no interelated models.

Answer (score 1):

The pagination you are doing is the best thing to do with along with indexing the products table. The problem with loading all the records at once will in a memory would also be not a good idea. If you do so, you have put all the results in an array and paginate it accordingly and that means you have to keep it synchronized in memory all the time. The other issue with this, if the records (products) get updated, it will not show up instantly till the array in memory is refreshed. Pagination works well when done in tandem with databases. I think you should try some other solution if this does not make sense to you.